Tp-link AX3000 Archer TX55E wifi adapter no longer found after update
After updating to Ubuntu 6.5.0-28-generic, my wifi adapter stopped being recognized. It had worked perfectly for the past month since first installing.
I am using a tp-link AX3000 Archer TX55E.
I tried the following:

Re-seating the wifi card in a different pcie slot.
Disabling and enabling "network stack" in BIOS.
Used lsmod | grep iwlwifi to confirm that the iwlwifi module is loaded.
and used ip link to confirm that the wireless interface is not listed.

Note: USB tethering to a cellphone works fine.

Reboot. At GRUB, select an older kernel. If the wifi begins to work, then file the appropriate bug report.
